# Timeout in $http.post not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've added a timeout on my `$http.post`. The reason is, when `$http.post` is called then it will communicate to the `$htt.post(url.com)` and if timeout is reached then it should stop the request of the url. Here's my code:

```
var canceler = $q.defer();
$http.post('www.example.com/api',{
    //some json data
}, {timeout: canceler.promise}).then(function(response){
    alert("Success");
});

// the timeout
$timeout(function(){
    $rootScope.$apply(function(){
        canceler.resolve();
        alert("Process stopped!");
    });
}, 40000);
```

As we can see, I set the timeout into 40seconds. Everytime the `$http.post` request is executed and it meets the 40seconds it will alert the `alert("Process stopped")` which is fine! But my problem is, when the request `$http.post` is executed less than 40seconds it still alerts the `alert("Process stopped!")` which should not be fired. Please help me. The alert should not be fired if the request is less than 40 seconds.

Comment: You need to check if the request has completed before you try and cancel it. BTW debugging use `alert()` isn't good because it stops the process. Better use console.log or better still the npm `debug` module

Comment: What do u mean? @Mikkel

Comment: Which part are you unclear about ? Your answer suggests you have taken the advice on board

Answer (score 0):

I just added a variable `isCompleted` which is boolean.

```
var isCompleted = false;
$http.post('url',{
  // datas
},{timeout:canceler.promise}).then(function(){
  // request completed
  isCompleted = true;
});

$timeout(function(){
    if(isCompleted == true){
       // Do nothing because already completed the request
    }else{
       // timeout of 40 seconds is reached. Notify User

            $rootScope.$apply(function(){
            $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: 'Oops, Something went wrong!',
                        template: 'It looks like that you\'re not connected to the internet or you have  a poor connection.'
                    });
                    canceler.resolve();


                });
    }
});
```